# PhpStorm shows all files as modified but they aren't

Tags: git, phpstorm

PhpStorm is showing that I have 6,327 files that are modified. These files have not been modified.

Git status shows no changes ready to commit.
Git add . doesn't do anything.

I am the only user of this code/repo.

Looks like these files are in my vendor directory (Laravel).

What can I do?

Comment: One possibility is that there is a line ending issue here.  Git is detecting that all the line endings have changed, when in fact logically they haven't.  Google around for this.

Comment: Most like the files in the vendor directory, is being tracked. And you might  have requested Composer to update the dependencies. [It is a good practice to add the vendor folder into .gitignore.](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/gitignore-what-should-be-ignored?page=1)

Comment: Yes, I agree. Ignoring vendor from now on. You should add this as an answer.